# Stored procedures in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a stored procedure in SQL Server which will accept two values `mlt_sk` (which is the serial key) and `GroupName`.

The user can enter multiple keys at single time, eg `mlt_sk` can be entered as `7,11,12` and group name as `xyz`. So the respective table should show result as 7,xyz 11,xyz,12-xyz. The result should be inserted into other table.

Comment: Wow! Do you have custom build from MS?

Comment: Look for TableValuedParameters

Comment: sorry for tag it is 2012

Comment: any one has sql script for the same then also be helpful

Comment: Ask your favorite search engine for samples - it'll provide you with lots of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using xml methods,

```
DECLARE @xml       XML,
        @mlt_sk    VARCHAR(100)='7,11,12',
        @GroupName VARCHAR(10)='xyz',
        @delimiter VARCHAR(10)=','
--- Converting string to XML
SET @xml = Cast(( '<X>'
                  + Replace(@mlt_sk, @delimiter, '</X><X>')
                  + '</X>' ) AS XML)

--SELECT @xml
DECLARE @YOUR_TABLE AS TABLE
  (
     VALUE VARCHAR(100)
  )

--------Use nodes() method
INSERT INTO @YOUR_TABLE
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') + '-' + @GroupName AS Value
FROM   @xml.nodes('X') AS T(N) 

SELECT * FROM @YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: working fine,thanks for your help...